# Working on While loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I was given a problem in my new programming class, and I've only ever used Python. Here is my problem:

> Write a program that prints the balance of an account after the first, second, and third year. The account has an initial balance of $1,000 and earns 5 percent interest per year.

I understand that my math may be flawed but the important thing is using the correct format and just getting my program to run. Here is my code:

```
public class P14MIS207 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int year_one_balance, month, x;
        year_one_balance = 1000;
        interest = (.05/12) * (year_one_balance);
        month = 0;
        x = 36;
        while(month <= x);
            month++;
            year_one_balance += interest;
            System.out.println(year_one_balance);
            // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, the problem you described seems like it would be better suited for a for loop since you know the max number of times you want to iterate, why use a while?

Comment: My experience with programming is very limited. It is just what I thought of using. No specific reason for it. You're probably right though, I'm sure a for loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: well a while loop is fine. For loops are good to learn though they are a fundamental just like while loops or if statements. The basic syntax is for(variable; condition; increment) {. So in your case here you might do for(int I =0; i < 3; i++) {

Comment: Thank you. That clears up a lot. coming from python, most of my errors have been syntax errors so it is nice to have support as I explore Java.

Comment: that's okay, I totally get that. I actually learned Java first and I'm trying to learn Python now and I was confused on for. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the semicolon after the `while` keyword, and you want to wrap the interior of the loop in curly braces (as opposed to how you use spaces in Python). Try:

```
while( month <= x){
    month++;
    year_one_balance += interest;
    System.out.println(year_one_balance);
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Comment: "You don't need the semicolon" is kind of an understatement. With the semicolon, the loop ends even before `month++`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. -

```
double principal=1000;
    int rate=5;
    double interest=0;
    int year=1;
    while(year<=3){
        interest=(principal*rate*year)/100;
        principal=principal+interest;
        System.out.println("Amount after "+year+" year is: $"+principal);
        year++;
    }
```

Comment: I realize now my error. I did not include the correct brackets for the while loop.